# jq filter to remove duplicates by comparing objects inside

Tags: json, object, duplicates, jq

I am trying to convert JSON lines to JSON and in the process trying to find and remove duplicates by comparing values from objects.

For example:

```
{"headline": "sample headline 1", "title": "sample title 1", "href": "sample link 1", "day": " Fri, 7 Jul 2017 , 8:30PM ", "tags": "tag1"}
{"headline": "sample headline 2", "title": "sample title 2", "href": "sample link 2", "day": " Fri, 7 Jul 2017 , 8:30PM ", "tags": "tag2"}
{"headline": "sample headline 3", "title": "sample title 3", "href": "sample link ", "day": " Fri, 7 Jul 2017 , 8:30PM ", "tags": "tag3"}
{"headline": "sample headline 4", "title": "sample title 1", "href": "sample link 4", "day": " Fri, 7 Jul 2017 , 8:30PM ", "tags": "tag4"}
```

Now I want to compare `title` from the first JSON line and the fourth JSON line, and if the  title is the same I want to omit one of the entries.

I have only been able to convert it to JSON and remove duplicates by comparing all objects:

```
jq --slurp [.[]] | unique
```

but this compares all objects inside whereas I want to compare only one object and remove the entire line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In words:

> .. to compare title from the first JSON line and the fourth JSON line, and if the title is the same I want to omit one of the entries.

In jq:

```
jq -s 'if .[0].title == .[3].title then del(.[0]) else . end'
```

---

In words:

> find and remove duplicates [based on .title]

In jq:

```
INDEX(.title) | [.[]]
```

Apart from brevity, the big advantage of using `INDEX/1` here (e.g. vs `unique` or `group_by`) is that it does NOT incur the cost of sorting.

(If your jq does not have `INDEX` then simply copy its definition from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq )

---

#### Using the -f option

Assuming you have jq 1.5 and that the file named program.jq contains the following text:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr|
      if type != "string" then tojson
      else .
      end] |= $row);
def INDEX(idx_expr): INDEX(.[]; idx_expr);

INDEX(.title) | [.[]]
```

you can invoke jq as follows:

```
jq -s -f program.jq input
```

where "input" is the name of the file containing the JSON lines (or JSON stream).

#### jq 1.4

If you only have access to jq 1.4, then you could use this variant:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr|
      if type != "string" then tojson
      else .
      end] |= $row);

INDEX(.[]; .title) | [.[]]
```

#### jq 1.3

jq 1.3 is very out-of-date but if you cannot upgrade, then for present purposes, it will suffice to use the version immediately above, replacing `tojson` with `tostring`. Or even just:

```
def INDEX(f): map( {(f|tostring): . } ) | add;
```

Comment: can you help me with the exact code when index is not defined. So find and remove duplicates based on title. INDEX(.title) | [.[]] returns and error. I am new to jq.  Thanks

Comment: I tried with above code got the following error 

error: tojson is not defined

      if type != "string" then tojson
                                ^^^^^^
error: too many arguments to INDEX (expected 1 but got 2)

def INDEX(idx_expr): INDEX(.[]; idx_expr);
                      ^^^^^
2 compile errors

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfect. my version is indeed 1.3 that is why there were errors.